# Stop offset and LinearGradient are the same thing?

Tags: svg

i'm Learning svg, so:

```
   <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
```

is where the gradient start (x1="0%" y1="0%") e where the gradient end (x2="100%" y2="0%")

but also

```
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:orange;stop-opacity:1" />
```

are where gradient start (first stop offset) e where end (second offset)

no ?

I don't understand what is the difference...
Maybe the difference is when there are more colurs and so is important to define where start and end all colurs with "stop offset" ?

Answer (score 2):

The attributes in the `<linearGradient>` tag determine the start and end coordinates of the linear gradient line.  The percentage values here are relative to the bounding box of the shape the gradient is being applied to.

`x1="0%" y1="0%"` means the top left.

`x2="100%" y2="0%"` means the top right.

So we are defining a horizontal linear gradient that runs from the LHS of the shape to the RHS.

The value of `offset` in the `<stop>` tags specifies a position along that line that each stop color starts.

So, in your example,

```
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
```

Specifies that the gradient is red at the 0% position (the left).

```
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:orange;stop-opacity:1" />
```

Specifies that the gradient is orange at the 100% position (the right).

So the final result is linear gradient that goes from red on the left to orange on the right.

Comment: So if i want a linear gradient with 4 colours, and with equal parts, it will be: <stop offset="0%" ... The second colur with 25%, third with 50% e finally with 75% ?

Comment: No, you will want to use 0%, 33% 67% and 100%.